# NodeJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when importing initializers from module

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use [nodeplotlylib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeplotlib) in NodeJS 10.5.0, but the import fails.

`import { plot, Plot } from 'nodeplotlib';` returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is for ES6 only.
You should use the following:

```js
const {plot, Plot} = require('nodeplotlib');
```

or

```js
const nodeplotlib = require('nodeplotlib');
// nodeplotlib.plot
// nodeplotlib.Plot
```

Comment: This syntax is es6 actually